# Binary grid data for splot command in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

This question is with reference to the `splot` command of the popular plotting program `gnuplot`. When I wan plot the so-called *grided data* from a datafile, we separate the rows by a blank record such as the datafile shown below

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4

0 1 -2
1 2 -3
2 3 -4

0 1 1.5
1 2 -1.2
2 3 4
```

How to do the same with **binary** datafile? In binary datafile, we simply store the records and we simply read the records sequentially as shown below

```
splot <file> binary format="%double%double%double" u 1:2:3
```

In this case, the data is read as un-gridded. How do I convert these data to grided data without using the `gnuplot`'s `dgrid3d` command. I don't wan to use the `dgrid3d` command as it unnecessarily tries to construct grided data from the already grided data, which is time consuming.

Any help will be welcome.

Madhurjya

Comment: Could you please somehow provide your binary example data file as download?

Comment: The binary data file is exactly what is shown above, but the data is dumped with FORTRAN unformatted stream and continuously written with sequence `x,y,z,x,y,z,...`.

So, in a sense there is no way to insert a 'blank line' in the binary format as required by `gnuplot` for gridded data

Comment: well, I know that will be just a sequence (probably of 32 bits floating point) numbers and I wanted to try a few things, but currently I don't know how to create a binary file with the ASCII content you showed above. Maybe you have a recommendation? Therefore, I was asking whether you could provide the actual ready-to-use binary file.

Comment: Why can't you use `matrix` in gnuplot? Check `help binary matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the data in your question is not "so-called grided data" because it represents just three repetitions of the three points (0,1), (1,2), and (2,3).
Presumably, the data you intend is the following data or something similar.

```
0 1 2
0 2 3
0 3 4

1 1 -2
1 2 -3
1 3 -4

2 1 1.5
2 2 -1.2
2 3 4
```

Assume that these nine (x,y,z) triplets are sequentially written out to a file as a flat binary where the individual numbers are of type 'double'. In that case, the binary keyword would need to be followed by the record keyword to tell the splot command that the file has a 3x3 grid structure.

```
splot "test.bin" binary record=(3,3) format ="%double%double%double"
```

Comment: Well, I found out the simpler way. Just like binzo said, you need to just dump the binary `z` data sequentially by scannning the row and then column (or vice versa). Then just use the command
```splot <binary file> binary array=MxN format="%doble"```
where  `M` and `N` are row and comun numbers.